# Laurent-series of $1/(z\,(1-z^2))$ at $z_0 = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I believe it's a slightly different series apart of all the others here.

As far as my solution process goes, I'm using partial fraction decomposition first:

$$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z\,(1-z^2)} = -\dfrac{1}{z}+\dfrac{1}{2\,(z-1)}+\dfrac{1}{2\,(z+1)}$$

and after rewriting:

$$f(z) = -\dfrac{1}{1-z+1}-\dfrac{1}{2}\,\dfrac{1}{1-z}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{1--z}$$

Now coming back to the geometric series: $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{k}=\dfrac{1}{1-z}}$

Based on the rewriting made easier $f(z)$ should equal $f(z) = -\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(z+1)^k+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z)^k}$

Sadly this is wrong.

Comment: I think partial fractions is the hard way, and error-prone. $1/(1-z^2)=1+z^2+z^4+\cdots$, now divide by $z$. Note that when $z=2$, the function is negative, but your partial fraction expression is positive.

Comment: Why do you want to transform the first term? The goal is to get a series in powers of $z$, with a finite number of negative powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake while decomposing into partial fractions..
$$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z}-\dfrac{1}{2\,(z-1)}-\dfrac{1}{2\,(z+1)}$$
Hence it can be re-written as
$$\dfrac{1}{z}+\dfrac{1}{2\,(1-z)}-\dfrac{1}{2\,(1-(-z))}$$
$$=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z)^k$$
Notice that when $k$ is even, the summations cancel each other. Hence,
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=-1}^{\infty}z^{2k+1}$$

Comment: There is no need to expand $\frac1z$, as that is already its Laurent series at $z_0=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, But since the OP had written the final answer in the form of summation, I guessed that they wanted it like that.

Comment: The stated task is to find the Laurent series, not some other composition.

Comment: Alright, thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my post

Comment: thanks guys. I also adapted my solutions. Less error prone.